# How to select ArangoSearch-View field from a specific link

Tags: arangodb, aql

Given the following `ArangoSearch View` definition, both collections `col_person` and `col_hotel` has a named field `f_name`.

```
{
  "cleanupIntervalStep": 2,
  "writebufferSizeMax": 33554432,
  "commitIntervalMsec": 1000,
  "id": "291316",
  "consolidationPolicy": {
    "type": "tier",
    "segmentsBytesFloor": 2097152,
    "segmentsBytesMax": 5368709120,
    "segmentsMax": 10,
    "segmentsMin": 1,
    "minScore": 0
  },
  "consolidationIntervalMsec": 1000,
  "globallyUniqueId": "h506F923AD141/291316",
  "links": {
    "col_person": {
      "analyzers": [],
      "fields": {
        "f_name": {
          "analyzers": [
            "arabic_text_analyzer",
            "arabic_collation_analyzer",
            "identity",
            "text_en"
          ]
        }
      },
      "includeAllFields": false,
      "storeValues": "none",
      "trackListPositions": false
    },
    "col_hotel": {
      "analyzers": [],
      "fields": {
        "f_name": {
          "analyzers": [
            "arabic_text_analyzer",
            "arabic_collation_analyzer",
            "text_en",
            "identity"
          ]
        }
      },
      "includeAllFields": false,
      "storeValues": "none",
      "trackListPositions": false
    }
  },
  "writebufferIdle": 64,
  "primarySort": [],
  "primarySortCompression": "lz4",
  "writebufferActive": 0,
  "storedValues": [],
  "type": "arangosearch"
}
```

The problem is that when executing the below AQL query ArangoDB searches in both collections' `f_name`, so how to search in only `col_person.f_name` not  in both.

```
LET QR1 = (
    FOR doc_asview_global1 IN asview_global1
    SEARCH
    ANALYZER(
        Like(doc_asview_global1.f_name, "%Regional%"),"identity") OR
    ANALYZER(
        LEVENSHTEIN_MATCH(doc_asview_global1.f_name, "Regional",1,true),"arabic_text_analyzer") OR
    ANALYZER(
        PHRASE(doc_asview_global1.f_name, "Regional"), "arabic_text_analyzer")
    LIMIT 10000
    SORT BM25(doc_asview_global1) DESC
    RETURN doc_asview_global1
)

RETURN QR1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `OPTIONS` to the `SEARCH` operation to specify the collections you are interested in:

```
SEARCH
  ...
  OPTIONS { collections: ["col_person"] }
```

https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operations-search.html#search-options